# Exception: Correlation failed. Unknown location

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, vue-cli-3

After identityserver authentication when it redirects to my application, it gives

**Exception: Correlation failed.
Unknown location**

Now because I am using SPA. This route is definitely not there. But question is how do I define one. And what should I do there.

I have used hybrid flow of Identityserver.

https://localhost:44375/signin-oidc

I have referred following.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/master/Clients/src/MvcHybridAutomaticRefresh/Startup.cs

But in above link there is a SPA middleware. which is VueCliMiddleWare. (And to me that is creating issue. routes.)

(For Rest of the routes it returns index file as per following code. Only this **/oidc-client** path is not working.)

```
     app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                await next();
            }
        })
.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions { DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { "index.html" } });
```

If I define following

```
routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa - fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "CatchAll", action = "Index" });
```

Then this route redirects to that controller. But there I am not able to return index file.

Comment: Are you wanting to manage the session serverside (cookie) or client side (bearer token)?

Comment: cookie. server side.

Comment: In that case the OIDC middleware should handle that request as `signin-oidc` is the default path. Can you post your OIDC middleware startup code please?

Comment: I have forked original author's repo and added my changes as below.
https://github.com/hnviradiya/asp-net-core-vue-starter/blob/master/Startup.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was mentioned as per below link that state property was missing.

But still I am not able to figure out how do I set one.

So not marking as accepted answer if someone has final answer.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7501#issuecomment-464082989

Updated:

Below is the answer to this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54721271/9263418

Answer (score 4):

As of 2020 you should be using https to resolve this

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

For development environments run `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` to trust the local certificates

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error with Amazon Cognito. My test User Pool was working fine (on localhost) but my production User Pool would not allow me to log in. I realised finally that the production User Pool also has a Client Secret (as well as a Client Id) which can be set via:
`services.AddOpenIdConnect(options => { ... options.ClientSecret = ...`

It's one of those issues which wasted hours but seems pretty obvious now!

Answer (score 0):

First check that you have

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> GetScopes()
        {
            return new List<ApiScope>
            {
                new ApiScope()
                {
                    Name = "catalogs"
                }
            };
        }
```

in your **config.cs** file. and if you are on a localhost you have to use the same address for your redirect_url in both IdentityServer and your client app.
(if you set the localhost in identityserver you have to use localhost for redirecturl in client app and not 127.0.0.1).
wish it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, but trying the methods above did not help me.  I found the answer by reading
https://devforum.okta.com/t/asp-net-core-correlation-failed-error-message/3563/15

To summarize, if you use

```
builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>
```

you must call

```
app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

later in your Program.cs (or equivalent for < donet 6) which solved my particular instance of the problem.

Hope this helps somebody.